# Iterating over dictionary with lists values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary and in one it's key/value, this value is a list. I'm trying to iterate over this dict to remove special characters (this is part is ok), but when I get this value (which is a list) I don't know how to do.

This is my dict:

```
{
  "id_pessoa_ies": "3",
  "cpf": "string",
  "nome": "TESTE COM Ç E ESPACO E É",
  "nome_social": "string",
  "sexo": "string",
  "data_nascimento": "26-11-2020",
  "cor_raca": "Preta",
  "estado_civil": "Test word here",
  "municipio_naturalidade": "Test again",
  "uf_naturalidade": "TEST",
  "pais_nascimento": "string",
  "docente_pessoa": [
    {
      "id_docente_ies": "string",
      "matricula": "123456789",
      "titulacao": "TEST",
      "ano_ingresso": "2020",
      "tipo_contrato": "string",
      "tipo_vinculo": "TESTE COM Ç E ESPACO E É ARROBA @ #",
      "id_unidade_lotacao": "1",
      "situacao": "ACTIVATE"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I did so far:

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
       if key == 'docente_pessoa':
           # what should I do here to iterate over 'docente_pessoa' to get it's values and
           # apply my function 'text_to_it()' on it?
       else:
           text = text_to_id(value)
           mydict.items[key] = text
```

I appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: `for docente_key, docente_val in value.items():` you can name variables anything you want. Basically, the same thing you have already done, but with different variable names. Also, since dictionaries are mutable, you can just do `val = text_to_id(val)` and it should have the same effect.

Comment: Hey @Tim thanks for your answer. I tried what you said and I got: `for docente_key, docente_val in value:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. Do you know what could be?

Comment: Yeah, I updated the first comment, it should be `for ... in value.items():` you already have the code, you just have to do it again, with different variable names. A loop inside a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its a list and has a `dict` in it, you could get it out like this:

```
docente_pessoa_dict = value[0]
```

Now you have a new set of values that you have to change I guess, so you could do this:

```
for key, value in docente_pessoa_dict.items():
    # do stuff with key and value
```

so to wrap it up:

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
       if key == 'docente_pessoa':
           docente_pessoa_dict = value[0]
           for key, value in docente_pessoa_dict.items():
               # do stuff with key and value
       else:
           # do stuff with key and value
```

Since the code that posted gives a `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` because you change the value while iterating `dict` which is completely unrelated to this question, you would have find a way to make a duplicate of the keys and then change the value.

You can do this by simply converting the your `dict` to `list` and then changing the `value`:

```
for key in list(mydict):
    if key == 'docente_pessoa':
        docente_pessoa_dict = mydict[key][0]
        for docente_pessoa_dict_key, docente_pessoa_dict_value in docente_pessoa_dict.items():
            text = text_to_id(docente_pessoa_dict_value)
            mydict[key][0][docente_pessoa_dict_key] = text 
    else:
        text = text_to_id(mydict[key])
        mydict[key] = text
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got this error `RuntimeError at xxxx
dictionary changed size during iteration`. When I added my mydict to update value inside the inner for. Do you know what could be?

Comment: @GuilhermeSchults well that is not part of your question, but take a look at this and I will update the answer

Comment: I aprecciate your help. I will take a look on this.

Comment: @GuilhermeSchults here you go, I updated the answer with correct way to do it, let me know if it works for you

Comment: It worked ! Thank you very much for your help and effort :)

Comment: @GuilhermeSchults I just fixed the code since the way it was it didn't change the value of the `docente_pessoa_dict_key` I fixed it now and it should do what you intended to if I understood correctly.